# Teradata DBS Error, Error: (CLI2: REQEXHAUST(307): Request data exhausted

Tags: teradata-sql-assistant

i am using source & target tables are Teradata , while running the mapping in informatica BDM , am getting error (
Teradata DBS Error, Error: (CLI2: REQEXHAUST(307): Request data exhausted)

Comment: Add more details with specific issue

Comment: This code indicates the Teradata driver already passed an _End Request_ to Informatica, but Informatica tried to fetch more data anyway. Perhaps you need to pursue this as an Informatica issue rather than a Teradata issue?